# How to see .htaccess files in Eclipse PDT?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-pdt

I can't seem to find/view .htaccess files in Eclipse PDT. I looked in the preferences, but couldn't find any relevant options when it came to hiding files. How can I enable this in Eclipse so I can edit .htaccess files?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

In the view on the left that shows all your files, click the little white down-arrow button on the view's toolbar.  That opens a menu that should have a "filters" or "customize view" option.

In the filters window, uncheck the ".* resources" item.  That'll make Eclipse show files whose name begins with a dot.